# Connection test and loop in case of lost connection to prevent end of script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have this script that runs continuously on a raspbery Zero to capture the temperatures and send them to grafana the problem is that when the grafana server is stopped for backup or something, the script falls in error and does not automatically resume so I’m looking for a way to create a connection test loop prealable to sending data and if the grafana server is off-service the continuous script worked until the grafana server was up and running and therefore resumed sending the temperature data to the grafana server.

Because current I end up with the script in error with in the message
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool`

To use script
`python templogger.py -db=influx_db_temperature -sn=temperature -rn=RUN`

My script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import glob
import argparse
import time
import datetime
import sys
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# add more sensor variables here based on your setup

# For multiple sensor
# temp=['sensor code','tttttttttt','ddddddddddd','ssssssssss']
temp=['0120215dbea2','0120327e05bf']
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'

# Ext = 28-0120215dbea2
# Int = 28-0120327e05bf

device_folders = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')

snum=2 #Number of connected temperature sensors

# Set required InfluxDB parameters.
# (this could be added to the program args instead of beeing hard coded...)
host = "NasGrafana.lan.prive" #Could also use local ip address like "192.168.1.136"
port = 8086
user = "temperature"
password = "12345678"
 
# Sample period (s).
# How frequently we will write sensor data from the temperature sensors to the database.
sampling_period = 120

def read_temp_raw(device_file): 
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines
 
def read_temp(device_file): # checks the temp recieved for errors
    lines = read_temp_raw(device_file)
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw(device_file)

    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        # set proper decimal place for C
        temp = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        # Round temp to 2 decimal points
        temp = round(temp, 1)
    # value of temp might be unknown here if equals_pos == -1
    return temp

def get_args():
    '''This function parses and returns arguments passed in'''
    # Assign description to the help doc
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Program writes measurements data from the connected DS18B20 to specified influx db.')
    # Add arguments
    parser.add_argument(
        '-db','--database', type=str, help='Database name', required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-sn','--session', type=str, help='Session', required=True)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    parser.add_argument(
        '-rn','--run', type=str, help='Run number', required=False,default=now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"))
    
    # Array of all arguments passed to script
    args=parser.parse_args()
    # Assign args to variables
    dbname=args.database
    runNo=args.run
    session=args.session
    return dbname, session,runNo
    
def get_data_points():
    # Get the three measurement values from the DS18B20 sensors
    for sensors in range (snum): # change number of sensors based on your setup
        device_file=device_folders[sensors]+ '/w1_slave'
        temp[sensors] = read_temp(device_file)
        print (device_file,sensors,temp[sensors])
    # Get a local timestamp
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
    NumDevice=os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(device_file))
    
    # Create Influxdb datapoints (using lineprotocol as of Influxdb >1.1)
    datapoints = [
        {
            "measurement": session,
            # "tags": {"runNum": NumDevice,},
            "tags": {"runNum": runNo,},
            "time": timestamp,
            #"fields": {"temperature 1":temp[0],"temperature 2":temp[1],"temperature 3":temp[2],"temperature 4":temp[3]}
            "fields": {"temperature 1":temp[0],"temperature 2":temp[1]}
        }
        ]
    return datapoints

# Match return values from get_arguments()
# and assign to their respective variables
dbname, session, runNo =get_args()   
print ("Session: ", session)
print ("Run No: ", runNo)
print ("DB name: ", dbname)

# Initialize the Influxdb client
client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
        
try:
     while True:
        # Write datapoints to InfluxDB
        datapoints=get_data_points()
        bResult=client.write_points(datapoints)
        print("Write points {0} Bresult:{1}".format(datapoints,bResult))
            
        # Wait for next sample
        time.sleep(sampling_period)
        
        # Run until keyboard ctrl-c
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Program stopped by keyboard interrupt [CTRL_C] by user. ")
```

Comment: Have you tried using ```try-except``` to prevent the exit?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I tested
```except:
    continue```
but I get the following error:
```>
> SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @AbhinavMathur for forcing me to stay on adding a try-except because in the end it’s just that I wasn’t positioning correctly in the script

This is the modif allowing the script to not crash with a connection error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import glob
import argparse
import time
import datetime
import sys
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# add more sensor variables here based on your setup

# For multiple sensor
# temp=['sensor code','tttttttttt','ddddddddddd','ssssssssss']
temp=['0120215dbea2','0120327e05bf']
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'

# Ext = 28-0120215dbea2
# Int = 28-0120327e05bf

device_folders = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')

snum=2 #Number of connected temperature sensors

# Set required InfluxDB parameters.
# (this could be added to the program args instead of beeing hard coded...)
host = "NasGrafana.lan.prive" #Could also use local ip address like "192.168.1.136"
port = 8086
user = "temperature"
password = "12345678"
 
# Sample period (s).
# How frequently we will write sensor data from the temperature sensors to the database.
sampling_period = 120

def read_temp_raw(device_file): 
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines
 
def read_temp(device_file): # checks the temp recieved for errors
    lines = read_temp_raw(device_file)
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw(device_file)

    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        # set proper decimal place for C
        temp = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        # Round temp to 2 decimal points
        temp = round(temp, 1)
    # value of temp might be unknown here if equals_pos == -1
    return temp

def get_args():
    '''This function parses and returns arguments passed in'''
    # Assign description to the help doc
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Program writes measurements data from the connected DS18B20 to specified influx db.')
    # Add arguments
    parser.add_argument(
        '-db','--database', type=str, help='Database name', required=True)
    parser.add_argument(
        '-sn','--session', type=str, help='Session', required=True)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    parser.add_argument(
        '-rn','--run', type=str, help='Run number', required=False,default=now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M"))
    
    # Array of all arguments passed to script
    args=parser.parse_args()
    # Assign args to variables
    dbname=args.database
    runNo=args.run
    session=args.session
    return dbname, session,runNo
    
def get_data_points():
    # Get the three measurement values from the DS18B20 sensors
    for sensors in range (snum): # change number of sensors based on your setup
        device_file=device_folders[sensors]+ '/w1_slave'
        temp[sensors] = read_temp(device_file)
        print (device_file,sensors,temp[sensors])
    # Get a local timestamp
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
    NumDevice=os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(device_file))
    
    # Create Influxdb datapoints (using lineprotocol as of Influxdb >1.1)
    datapoints = [
        {
            "measurement": session,
            # "tags": {"runNum": NumDevice,},
            "tags": {"runNum": runNo,},
            "time": timestamp,
            #"fields": {"temperature 1":temp[0],"temperature 2":temp[1],"temperature 3":temp[2],"temperature 4":temp[3]}
            "fields": {"temperature 1":temp[0],"temperature 2":temp[1]}
        }
        ]
    return datapoints

# Match return values from get_arguments()
# and assign to their respective variables
dbname, session, runNo =get_args()   
print ("Session: ", session)
print ("Run No: ", runNo)
print ("DB name: ", dbname)

# Initialize the Influxdb client
client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
        
try:
     while True:
        # Write datapoints to InfluxDB
        datapoints=get_data_points()
        try:
            bResult=client.write_points(datapoints)
            print("Write points {0} Bresult:{1}".format(datapoints,bResult))
        except:
            print("Error lan connection")
            #time.sleep(30)
            #continue
            
        # Wait for next sample
        time.sleep(sampling_period)
        
        # Run until keyboard ctrl-c
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Program stopped by keyboard interrupt [CTRL_C] by user. ")
```